# Azure Logic App Step Fail Monitoring with Alerts sent

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-monitoring

We have a logic app little complex and it has a step in whcih we Create a File and Upload it, this step can fail sometimes.

What we would like to do is Monitor this step over a period of 3 hour and if this step fails like more than 10 times in that 3 hour period we would like to send an alert to a team.

Unfortunately I have not been able to find out a way to perform this. One thing I thought was every failure of this step should be recorded in Log Analytics workspace and may be we can query that workspace for such errors and then generate alert from it.

Anyone aware of how we can monitor a STEP in Azure Logic Apps for failure over a 3 hour period and then generate an alert? All this has to be done with out of the box Azure and not looking for any third party paid solutions.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ty but this option we had already explored and doesnt help for our requirements. We  were looking for Monitoring soln and finally we got this query and an Alert out of it to make it work for our requirement:-

`AzureDiagnostics
| where
 status_s == "Failed"and
 tags_displayName_s =="My Logic Apps Name"and
 resource_actionName_s in ("For_each_file_in_blob_copy_it_to_sftp_server","Create_file_on_SFMC_SFTP_folder")
| summarizecount()by resource_runId_s, resource_actionName_s, tags_displayName_s, status_s`

Using the above Query we created a New Alert and this currently works for our monitoring requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? [action groups?](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/azure/azure-monitor/platform/action-groups)

Some of the possible rules, such as `Actions Failed` could work on a greater than errors per hour count.

[image: Action Group rule]

Otherwise, would it be possible to call on the logic app from the logic app where if the step fails, call upon it with the file that failed to try to redo the operation? Like an 'unsuccessful run after action'?

I guess you could also on an unsuccessful action post to a slack channel.

Comment: ty but this option we had already explored and doesnt help for our requirements. We  were looking for Monitoring soln and finally we got this query and an Alert out of it to make it work for our requirement:-  AzureDiagnostics
| where
 status_s == "Failed"and
 tags_displayName_s =="My Logic Apps Name"and
 resource_actionName_s in ("For_each_file_in_blob_copy_it_to_sftp_server","Create_file_on_SFMC_SFTP_folder")
| summarizecount()by resource_runId_s, resource_actionName_s, tags_displayName_s, status_s

Comment: Interesting, cheers for sharing a solution that worked for you!